# ComboBox linked cell display in excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Within `Workbook1`, I have 2 Sheets, for simplicity I'll call them `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

On `Sheet1` I have a Combo Box called `ComboBox1`, the Combo Box has values in it from cells `A1:A114`. The linked cell for the Combo Box is `G13` on `Sheet1`.

My issue is, when I pick a value from the Combo Box, I want a value to appear in the linked cell from `Sheet2`.

For example, if I select the value from `A1` in `Sheet1`, then the value of `Sheet2!$D$2` appears in the linked cell `(G13)`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Look up format control for your combo box and your issue will be solved

Comment: I'm not sure where `Sheet2!$D$2` comes into this. What would you expect to happen if you selected a different option in your ComboBox, say the one that relates to `A2`?

Comment: A1 on Sheet1 relates to D2 on Sheet2
A2 relates to D3
A3 to D4, and so on

Comment: but why https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--lQ4fx0tr--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/wnfyyiakckla7hs0ptqb.jpg

Comment: Ok... I have a load of raw data on Sheet2 (answers to questions in this case). On Sheet1 I have a combo box with the questions in. When I select a question from the combo box I want the corresponding answer (from Sheet2) to appear in the linked cell which is G13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly - the linked cell has to hold the value of the ComboBox. However, if you don't mind an additional step, then the following formula in any other cell on `Sheet1` will give the result you want:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$115,MATCH($G$13,$A$1:$A$114,0))
```

Comment: Thank you, at least someone was trying to help!